# getting error while calling toJson method due to Color type in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a class that contains Color datatype....while calling toJson its generate an error of Color datatype...

If i convert code to color.toString it works fine but than how to convert string to color in fromJson method...

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'detail': detail,
      'edittedOn': edittedOn.toString(),
      'color': color,// if i change to color.toString() its working but how to convert in  fromJson from string to color
      'isLocked':isLocked,
    };
  }

  factory Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Note(
      id: map['id'],
      title: map['title'],
      detail: map['detail'],
      edittedOn:DateTime.now(),
      color:  map['color'],
      isLocked: map['isLocked'],

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating convertor method from String to Color

```
Color colorFromString(String colorString)
{
  String splitString=
  colorString.split('(0x')[1].split(')')[0];

  int value=int.parse(splitString,radix: 16);
  Color newColor= Color(value);

  return newColor;


}
```